# Using bootstrap Modal in a TypeScript simple webapp

Tags: typescript, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-5

I'd like to use bootstrap `Modal` component in my TS app.
So, I installed the types

```
npm i @types/bootstrap
```

and then in my TS code

```js
import { Modal } from "bootstrap";
const myModal = new Modal('#myModal');
```

When I try to compile I get:

> ````
> TS2792: Cannot find module '@popperjs/core'. Did you mean to set the
> 'moduleResolution' option to 'nodenext', or to add aliases to the
> 'paths' option?
>
> 1 import * as Popper from '@popperjs/core';
>                           ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>
> node_modules/@types/bootstrap/js/dist/tooltip.d.ts:1:25 - error
> TS2792: Cannot find module '@popperjs/core'. Did you mean to set the
> 'moduleResolution' option to 'nodenext', or to add aliases to the
> 'paths' option?
>
> 1 import * as Popper from '@popperjs/core';
>                           ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>
>
> Found 2 errors in 2 files.
>
> Errors  Files
>      1  node_modules/@types/bootstrap/js/dist/dropdown.d.ts:1
>      1  node_modules/@types/bootstrap/js/dist/tooltip.d.ts:1 ```
> ````

If I do as the error message suggests, and adds `"moduleResolution": "NodeNext"`, i am able to successfully compile, however in runtime I see an error in the console:

> Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "bootstrap". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../".

So how do I open a Bootstrap modal with TypeScript?

Comment: You've installed the TypeScript _types_ for Bootstrap. Have you installed _Bootstrap_?

Comment: @isherwood yes i have. doesn't help...

Comment: Have you installed Popper too with `npm i @popperjs/core` or by using the CDN version in Bootstrap doc (https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.11.8/dist/umd/popper.min.js)?
Popper is needed for elements such as dropdowns, tooltips, etc.

Comment: @JulienDéramond I have, and it didn't help...

Comment: I had couple of times the same issue and could not resolve it. Also installing `npm install @popperjs/core` does not help. Typescript seem to need more information for module resolution.